# how to await until parallel task done

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, c#-7.0, c#-7.2

I'm new with C#. I'm writing window form for sorting files inside folder according to it extension.
It's work when do the task with one folder but I modified it to do it from multiple item in listbox.

```
private async void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.listBox1.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        this.statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
        this.statusLabel.Text = "Sorting";
        this.startBtn.Enabled = false;
        this.removeOtherCheck.Enabled = false;
        this.workerCounter.Enabled = false;
        foreach (var item in this.listBox1.Items)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists( (string)item ))
            {
               await Task.Run(() => startTask((string)item, this.removeOtherCheck.Checked, this.workerCounter.TabIndex));
            }
        }
        FinishedTask();
    }
    private async void startTask(string path, bool removeOtherFlag, int worker)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => doJob(path, removeOtherFlag, worker));
    }
    private void FinishedTask()
    {
        this.statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        this.statusLabel.Text = "Finished";
        this.startBtn.Enabled = true;
        this.removeOtherCheck.Enabled = true;
        this.workerCounter.Enabled = true;
    }
//this method are seperate but I put it here so you guy can see it
        public static void doJob(string directory,bool removeOtherFlag, int worker)
        {
            // loop in directory
            createFolders(directory); // create extension folder
            string[] all_files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
            Parallel.ForEach(all_files, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = worker }, (item) => multiprocessingFiles(item));

            }
        if(removeOtherFlag == true) deleteOtherFolder(Path.Combine(directory,"other"));
        removeEmptyFolder(directory); // remove empty extension folder
    }
```

I'm gonna explain my task.
first I click start button when process start it will disable all buttons, then loop for each items in listbox and sorting all files in folder.
when everything finished it will show finished label and enable all buttons.

the thing is, it show finished label and re-enable all buttons before removeEmptyFolder() doing it job.

I try change Parallel.forEach to Parallel.For but it's not doing my thing.

**EDIT**
Thank you for all answer.
Thank Harald Coppoolse for your conclusion.
Paulo Morgado is right.

I remove startTask and change

```
await Task.Run(() => startTask((string)item, this.removeOtherCheck.Checked, this.workerCounter.TabIndex));
```

to

```
await Task.Run(() => doJob(item, this.removeOtherCheck.Checked, this.workerCounter.TabIndex));
```

Now everything is working perfectly as I want.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: What is the implementation of `multiprocessingFiles`, `deleteOtherFolder` and `removeEmptyFolder`? Are they asynchronous?

Comment: It's really unlikely that using `Parallel.ForEach` will improve the speed in which your code runs. Accessing the disk is orders of magnitude slower than sorting a bunch of strings. Unless there's more work being performed than sorting.

Comment: deleteOtherFolder,removeEmptyFolder not asynchronous it need to wait until parallel.ForEach finished

Comment: You need to show us the `multiprocessingFiles` method. As a side note, method names in C# follow the PascalCase pattern. `MultiprocessingFiles` is correct.

Comment: Never mind, here is your problem: `private async void startTask`. [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: The best thing to do with `startTask` is just deleting it.

Comment: I didn't show multiprocessingFiles because it just check for extension of files and move file to it extension directory

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for someting like `Task.WaitAll(params Task[] tasks)`?

Then you could cange `doJob` to async by,
replaceing `Parallel.ForEach` with:

```cs
var tasks = all_files.Select(f => Task.Run(multiprocessingFiles(f)));
await Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Or if you want to limit the max parallel tasks:
Create non running tasks via `Task t = new Task(() => doSometing());`
and start them in batches with `t.Start();` and `await Task.WaitAll(batch);`

However as pointed out in the comments I do not think this will improve performace.

Comment: before this, it sorting 5 files in directory at the same time like python threadpool.

but that version only work with one directory from input text.

I change input text to listbox and do sorting in all items in listbox.

maybe not use Parallel will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In winforms, when you use async-await, you only use `Task.Run` when you need to start an extra thread that will do a job that takes some considerable amount of time, longer than you want your program to freeze. You don't call Task.Run for async methods, because properly designed async methods won't freeze your UI.

As soon as a thread that executes an async method sees `await`, it doesn't wait idly for the procedure until it is finished, instead if goes up its call stack to execute code until is sees an await. Goes up the call stack again, and executes code until is sees an await, etc.

Result: if an async event handler only uses async methods, your UI won't freeze. Unless one of the async methods does some heavy calculations (= use long non-async functionality)

If you want to keep your UI responsive during those heavy calculations, you should create an async method that calls the procedure with the heavy calculations using `Task.Run`.

**But I did all that!**

Yes you did, but you also had an async function that called another async fucntion using Task.Run! And that was not necessarry.

BTW, it might be a good idea to stick to coding conventions, like using camel casing and adding Async in async methods. This will help future readers to understand your code.

```
void DoJob(...){...}     // your time consuming method with heavy calculations
```

The async version of DoJob. Apparently there is nothing we can do async in DoJob, so this version has to call the DoJob:

```
async Task DoJobAsync(...)
{
    // call the non-async version on a separate thread:
    await Task.Run( () => DoJob(...)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I named the procedure DoJobAsync, because the pre- and postconditions are the same as in DoJob. This matches all other non-async / async pairs: Stream.Write and Stream.WriteAsync, File.Read and File.ReadAsync, Queryable.ToList and Queryable.ToListAsync.

If in future versions DoJobAsync can use some async methods, for instance because someone invents a procedure `MultiprocessingFilesAsync`, then only DoJobAsync has to change, no one else will know.

For `ConfigureAwait(false)` see Stephen Cleary's [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming][1]

BTW: are you sure that it is wise to do the disk handling in a Parallel.Foreach? Did you measure that it is more efficient than a standard foreach?

Anyway, apparently you have some user interface element that will start the process of "doing the job" While this job is being processed, you want to give some visual information to the operator that the job is busy, and you want to tell the operator that the job is finished. You already invented `FinishedTask`, why not create a `StartTask` (and use better descriptive names: verbs for methods)

```
void ShowTaskStarted() {...}
void ShowTaskCompleted() {...}    // was: FinishedTask
```

Apparently the items in listBox1 are strings.

```
async Task ProcessItems(IEnumerable<string> itemsToProcess,
           bool removeOtherFlag, int worker)  // TODO: invent proper name
{
    foreach (string itemToProcess in itemsToProcess)
    {
        await DoJobAsync(itemToProcess, removeOtherFlag, worker);
    }
}
```

If you think that you can start a second DoJobAsync before the first has completely finished, then start the next job before the previous one is completed:

```
List<Task> jobs = new List<Task>();
foreach (string itemToProcess in itemsToProcess)
{
    Task jobTask = DoJobAsync(itemToProcess, removeOtherFlag, worker);
    jobs.Add(jobTask);
}
await Task.WhenAll(jobs);
```

Because you job is some disk handling, I'm not sure it is wise to do this, but keep this in mind, if for instance you are starting tasks which can be startedwhile the previous one is not finished.

Until now, the procedures didn't know that the data came from a listbox, nor from a CheckBox or a TabControl. I did this, because if later you decide to change the source of the data, for instance a ComboBox, or a DataGridView, these procedures don't have to change. Below is the first procedure that knows about your form.

This is a strict separation of your Model (= data and how the data is processed) and the View (= how the data is displayed).

Other advantages of separating your Model from your View:

- you can put the Model outside you Form (the Form HAS the Model = aggregation, or composition). This way, this Model can be used by several Forms.
- a separated Model can be unit tested without the Form
- If you give the Model an interface, you can change the Model, without having to change the Form.
- With the interface, you can mock the model during development of your interface.

So consider to always separate your Model from your View.

### The View

I don't know what is in your listbox, so I can't give the next procedure a proper name.

```
async Task ProcessListBox()          // TODO: proper name
{
    ShowTaskStarted();

    var itemsToProcess = this.ListBox1.Items.ToList();
    var removeOtherCheck = this.removeOtherCheck.Checked;
    var worker = this.workerCounter.TabIndex;
    await ProcessItems(itemsToProcess, removeOtherCheck, worker);

    ShowTaskCompleted();
}
```

And finally: you want to process the ListBox when the operator clicks the start button:

```
async void StartButton_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    await ProcessLisbBox().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Because I separated the action (what must be done) from the trigger (when must it be done), the following will be a one liner method:

```
async void MenuItem_EditStart_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    await ProcessLisbBox().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Or maybe you want to do it during loading the form: add one line is enough

### Conclusions

- When using async-await: go async all the way.
- async methods always call async versions of other methods
- If a time consuming method doesn't have an async alternative, create one, and let it `Task.Run` the non-async version. Outside this procedure no one knows that a separate thread is started.
- conventions: async methods are suffixed Async
- Don't make one procedure that does everything. Smaller procedures are easier to understand, easier to reuse, easier to change and to unit test
- Separate the model from the view, preferably using an interface
- CamelCase your Methods, use Verbs.
  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming